# Complex conditional df subsetting with nested for loops in r

Tags: r, range, nested-for-loop

I apologize in advance for this headache, and in particular, the minimum amount of data I need to give you to reproduce my situation.

I have two data frames that look like:

```
> dput(df_long[1:60,])
structure(list(id = c("20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", 
"20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", 
"20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", 
"20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", 
"20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", 
"20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", "20230420-02", 
"20230420-02", "20230420-02"), condition = c("control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control"), pairscores = c(4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1), round = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"
), win = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1), sound = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 8, 
8, 8), ttrs = c(34.8679761886597, 53.7323212623596, 72.872288942337, 
95.00337266922, 108.467720985413, 127.519412279129, 140.932771205902, 
152.619723320007, 164.774888753891, 189.440443992615, 199.848607540131, 
211.736871480942, 228.6589448452, 240.730955839157, 258.806998729706, 
272.826892614365, 285.802761793137, 301.402906894684, 314.37718629837, 
330.579266309738, 342.812170028686, 353.819888830185, 370.405727863312, 
379.25874209404, 386.349495410919, 398.328526258469, 408.155629873276, 
420.099550485611, 430.813805341721, 441.291796922684, 34.8679761886597, 
53.7323212623596, 72.872288942337, 95.00337266922, 108.467720985413, 
127.519412279129, 140.932771205902, 152.619723320007, 164.774888753891, 
189.440443992615, 199.848607540131, 211.736871480942, 228.6589448452, 
240.730955839157, 258.806998729706, 272.826892614365, 285.802761793137, 
301.402906894684, 314.37718629837, 330.579266309738, 342.812170028686, 
353.819888830185, 370.405727863312, 379.25874209404, 386.349495410919, 
398.328526258469, 408.155629873276, 420.099550485611, 430.813805341721, 
441.291796922684), ttbp = c(42.8691244125366, 57.7340142726898, 
79.8788452148437, 101.018859148026, 114.473237752914, 130.520850658417, 
144.944416761398, 158.633060216904, 173.786515951157, 193.448391675949, 
203.859516382217, 220.743315935135, 233.666549682617, 249.745782613754, 
265.810203790665, 278.836834669113, 291.811623334885, 302.416656732559, 
320.388904809952, 335.58996462822, 347.819845914841, 361.828748226166, 
372.408302783966, 380.263983488083, 390.360696315765, 402.329761266708, 
411.160075902939, 425.111953496933, 435.816273927689, 450.295118093491, 
42.8691244125366, 57.7340142726898, 79.8788452148437, 101.018859148026, 
114.473237752914, 130.520850658417, 144.944416761398, 158.633060216904, 
173.786515951157, 193.448391675949, 203.859516382217, 220.743315935135, 
233.666549682617, 249.745782613754, 265.810203790665, 278.836834669113, 
291.811623334885, 302.416656732559, 320.388904809952, 335.58996462822, 
347.819845914841, 361.828748226166, 372.408302783966, 380.263983488083, 
390.360696315765, 402.329761266708, 411.160075902939, 425.111953496933, 
435.816273927689, 450.295118093491), ttbi = c(50.7323212623596, 
69.872288942337, 92.00337266922, 105.467720985413, 124.519412279129, 
137.932771205902, 149.619723320007, 161.774888753891, 186.440443992615, 
196.848607540131, 208.736871480942, 225.6589448452, 237.730955839157, 
255.806998729706, 269.826892614365, 282.802761793137, 298.402906894684, 
311.37718629837, 327.579266309738, 339.811122179031, 350.818850278854, 
367.405727863312, 376.25874209404, 383.348484039307, 395.328526258469, 
405.155629873276, 417.099550485611, 427.813805341721, 438.291796922684, 
454.063094377518, 50.7323212623596, 69.872288942337, 92.00337266922, 
105.467720985413, 124.519412279129, 137.932771205902, 149.619723320007, 
161.774888753891, 186.440443992615, 196.848607540131, 208.736871480942, 
225.6589448452, 237.730955839157, 255.806998729706, 269.826892614365, 
282.802761793137, 298.402906894684, 311.37718629837, 327.579266309738, 
339.811122179031, 350.818850278854, 367.405727863312, 376.25874209404, 
383.348484039307, 395.328526258469, 405.155629873276, 417.099550485611, 
427.813805341721, 438.291796922684, 454.063094377518)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the other one I must upload as a .txt file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oZ-0y5rAEsEuQ0gA_9bdWH6fr4wT7xkJ/view?usp=sharing)

I would like to get a mean of each emotion in au_slim within au_slim$timestamp ranges equal to range df_long$ttbi - 1 to df_long$ttbi - 1 for each row in df_long. I need to keep track of these by the id in each df, and by the df_long$win associated with each df_long$ttbi. My expected output would be a new df that looks something like:

| id | win | ttbi | happiness | sadness | surprise | fear | anger | disgust |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230420-01 | 1 | 1 | # | # | # | # | # | # |
| 20230420-01 | 0 | 2 | # | # | # | # | # | # |
| 20230420-01 | 1 | 3 | # | # | # | # | # | # |

This would, of course, continue for all ids, where each id would have 30 rows (for the 30 ttbi's). I have been poking at this for a few days with basically no success. Frankly, I am just way in over my head code-wise. I know I need to use a for loop to iterate through each id, and probably a nested for loop to run each ttbi in each id. Any help would be great.

*Note that a lot of the cells in the new df will be 0 (or very close to it). That's fine.

EDIT by request:

df_long had more ids, but I have now corrected that:

```
> unique(au_slim$id) %in% unique(df_long_vid$id)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[20] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[39] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> unique(df_long_vid$id) %in% unique(au_slim$id)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[20] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[39] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

When I run the code with the updated df, I still receive:

```
> library(dplyr)
> # Add round column to au_slim
> au_slim$round <- NA
> for(i in unique(au_slim$id)) {
+   # Get ttbi values for current id
+   breaks <- df_long_vid[which(df_long_vid$id == i), "ttbi"]
+   for(j in 1:length(breaks)) {
+     # Assign game round value to au_slim$round where timestamp values 
+     # are -/+ 1 of breaks[j] 
+     au_slim[which(au_slim$id == i & 
+                     au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j]-1 & 
+                     au_slim$timestamp <= breaks[j]+1), "round"] <- j
+   }
+ }
Error in which(au_slim$id == i & au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j] - 1 &  : 
  dims [product 30] do not match the length of object [637610]
In addition: Warning message:
In au_slim$id == i & au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j] - 1 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

```
> dput(head(au_slim))
structure(list(id = c("20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01"), timestamp = c(0, 
0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2), happiness = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    sadness = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), surprise = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), fear = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), anger = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), disgust = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), round = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT for another problem:

After solving the data.table vs. data.frame issue, the first half of the solution runs without an error. But it does not fill au_slim$round as expected. See:

```
> for(i in unique(au_slim$id)) {
+   # Get ttbi values for current id
+   breaks <- df_long_vid[which(df_long_vid$id == i), "ttbi"]
+   for(j in 1:length(breaks)) {
+     # Assign game round value to au_slim$round where timestamp values 
+     # are -/+ 1 of breaks[j] 
+     au_slim[which(au_slim$id == i & 
+                     au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j]-1 & 
+                     au_slim$timestamp <= breaks[j]+1), "round"] <- j
+   }
+ }
> dput(head(au_slim))
structure(list(id = c("20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01", 
"20230420-01", "20230420-01", "20230420-01"), timestamp = c(0, 
0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2), happiness = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    sadness = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), surprise = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), fear = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), anger = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), disgust = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), round = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

What is `NA_integer_`?

Comment: Regarding my answer, if you comment here about the extra bin issue and how you want to deal with it, I'll update my answer so you can join the result back to df_long.

Comment: Hey @LeroyTyrone, this is looking great so far, thanks! re. 454.06309: oops, I hadn't noticed that before... that is just due to imperfect timing between the two systems that recorded this data. Is there a way to make it take ttbi-1 to ttbi +1, unless ttbi > than max timestamp, in which case take ttbi-2 to max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This approach has been tested using the full df_long file and the subset sample of au_slim that has 23,020 rows. Given the "ttbi" values vary between "id" values, the nested for loop first loops through each "id", then through the corresponding "ttbi" values and assigns the bin values. Then `summarise()` from the `dplyr` package calculates the mean values for each emotion:

```
library(dplyr)

# Add round column to au_slim
au_slim$round <- NA

for(i in unique(au_slim$id)) {
  
  # Get ttbi values for current id
  breaks <- df_long[which(df_long$id == i), "ttbi"]
  
  for(j in 1:length(breaks)) {
    
    # Assign game round value to au_slim$round where timestamp values 
    # are -/+ 1 of breaks[j] 
    au_slim[which(au_slim$id == i & 
                    au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j]-1 & 
                    au_slim$timestamp <= breaks[j]+1), "round"] <- j
    
  }
  
}

# Summarise values
test <- au_slim %>%
  # Remove rows not within -/+ 1 of ttbi break value
  filter(!is.na(round)) %>%
  # Group by id and round and calculate mean for each subgroup and emotion
  group_by(id, round) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(happiness:disgust), mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Join df_long data and select desired columns
  left_join(df_long, by = c("id", "round")) %>%
  select(id, win, ttbi = "round", happiness:disgust)

data.frame(head(test))
           id win ttbi happiness    sadness surprise fear anger    disgust
1 20230420-01   1    1    0.3475 0.13413333   0.0084    0     0 0.16213333
2 20230420-01   0    2    0.1930 0.01593333   0.0000    0     0 0.05020000
3 20230420-01   1    3    1.4270 0.04226667   0.0000    0     0 0.14613333
4 20230420-01   1    4    1.4111 0.02106667   0.1244    0     0 0.03733333
5 20230420-01   1    5    0.5502 0.25593333   0.0000    0     0 0.44266667
6 20230420-01   1    6    0.0000 0.73880000   0.4627    0     0 0.00000000

data.frame(tail(test))
           id win ttbi happiness    sadness surprise fear   anger    disgust
1 20230420-02   0   25    1.1532 0.22020000  0.00000    0 0.00000 0.61713333
2 20230420-02   0   26    1.6466 0.00380000  0.00000    0 0.04685 0.08726667
3 20230420-02   1   27    1.2871 0.10366667  0.00000    0 0.00000 0.08820000
4 20230420-02   1   28    0.9057 0.15060000  0.00000    0 0.00000 0.65953333
5 20230420-02   1   29    0.6546 0.12673333  0.02355    0 0.00540 0.75526667
6 20230420-02   1   30    1.4935 0.05133333  0.00000    0 0.02190 0.63586667
```

Comment: Thanks again @LeroyTyrone. Please see my comment re bins above.  I am a little confused by the df created by this code though. It appears that the first id has 597 bins where you seem to be saying that there should be 31? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In case we are getting different results, here is what I get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTrcFlVsz4bh7Lkw0OKzFUyOryGlihuM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @grace.cutler - a few quick questions before I can update my answer: 1) What is the result if your run `length(unique(df_long$ttbi))`? If the result is != 30, we used different versions of df_long. 2) Related to question 1, are the bin cutoff values the same for each "id" e.g. 30 values from 50.73232,  69.87229,  92.00337, ..., 454.06309? 3) Relating to your comment on your question above, I assume you mean  combine everything > 438.29180 e.g. ignore the 454.06309 cut value? Thankfully all of these issues are easy to fix.

Comment: I get the same thing when using 'length(unique(df_long$ttbi))'. I double checked and we are using the same df_long. I am just going to upload the full df_long in case something weird is going on in the portion I did not provide above. As for ttbi values: no, ttbi is the time in seconds at which some specific thing occurred in the gameplay (happens once per round). So the ttbi of every round will be different for all of the ids. I am trying to get a mean of the emotions in au_slim in a range of +/- each ttbi (such that the resulting df will be 30 rows per id, each row representing on round

Comment: I ran out of characters above but I hope that clarifies things? Just to double clarify, each timerange I am looking for would be 2 seconds long (1 second before ttbi to 1 second after). Here is the full df_long: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wvrMKAFE_oMznC2Ja6RUFvFGFkeo6UNB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @grace.cutler ah, apologies, I now understand the bin issue. As for the number of bins, not sure why there's a difference. Will look into it and update the answer asap.

Comment: @grace.cutler - it should be fully working now. The updated version can accommodate varying ttbi values per id. The previous version used every unique ttbi regardless of which id they belonged to, which is why 597 bins were returned. Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Wow! I am continually impressed by the things r can do. But I am getting this error: 'Error in which(au_slim$id == i & au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j] - 1 &  : 
  dims [product 30] do not match the length of object [637610]
In addition: Warning message:
In au_slim$id == i & au_slim$timestamp >= breaks[j] - 1 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length'

Comment: 637610 is the length of the full au_slim, so it must not be running 'au_slim$id == i' properly for some reason? It looks like it should work. Note that I get the same error when I use the partial au_slim file I uploaded for this question (but with "length of object [23020]").

Comment: @grace.cutler 1) After the error, what is the value assigned to i? 2) Run dput(head(au_slim)) and add results into a codeblock in your question. 3) Is every "id" value in df_long present in au_slim?

Comment: @grace.cutler For point 3) above, run unique(au_slim$id) %in% unique(df_long$id). Any FALSE values mean not every id is in both dataframes.

Comment: I have updated the question with the info requested :) I accidentally tried to edit your answer instead of my question and I now cannot seem to take back the edit request. Sorry about that

Comment: Mystery solved, and I replicated your issue at my end to confirm. You need to convert au_slim and df_long to `data.frame()` objects., they are currently in `data.table()` format. Use `au_slim <- data.frame(au_slim)` etc. Perhaps make backups of your data tables first. Apologies, I should have advised you to `dput()` your data earlier. Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: No, it is my fault, I should have known. I am still having a problem, though. Now the first part of the code runs with no errors, but au_slim$round is entirely just NAs (and so the second part is not running). I will add this to the question above.

Comment: @grace.cutler - As per SO suggestion, I've moved commenting to chat, hopefully the they show up in your inbox.